# How can two Haskell programs exchange an integer value via stdin and stdout without treating the data as text?

Tags: parsing, haskell, stdout, stdin

I am interested in learning how to send data efficiently between Haskell programs using standard input and output. Suppose I want to pipe two programs together: "P1" outputs the number 5 to stdout, and "P2" takes an integer from stdin, adds 1, and outputs it to stdout again. Right now, the best way I know to do this involves outputting the data as text from P1, parsing that text back to an integer in P2, and proceeding from there. For example:

P1.hs:

```
module Main where

main = do
  print 5
```

P2.hs:

```
module Main where

main = fmap manipulateData getLine >>= print
  where
    manipulateData = (+ 1) . (read :: String -> Int)
```

Output:

```
$ (stack exec p1) | (stack exec p2)
6
```

I'd like to use standard i/o to send an integer without treating it as text, if possible. I'm assuming this still requires some sort of parsing to work, but I'm hoping it's possible to parse the data as binary and get a faster program.

Does Haskell have any way to make this straightforward? Since I am going from one fundamental Haskell datatype (Int) to the same type again with a pass through standard i/o in the middle, I'm wondering if there is an easy solution that doesn't require writing a custom binary parser (which I don't know how to do). Can anyone provide such a method?

Comment: Use serialization. I'd recommend: https://www.stackage.org/package/persist

Comment: Thanks - I'm giving this a look now. Will hopefully answer the question in a little while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that I ended up with:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import qualified Data.Binary as B

main :: IO ()
main = do
  dat <- BS.getContents
  print $ (B.decode dat :: Int) + 1
```

The other program uses similar imports and outputs 5 with the following line:

```
BS.putStr $ B.encode (5 :: Int)
```

The resulting programs can be piped together, and the resulting program behaves as required.

Comment: I can't say much about whether this is a *good* answer, because I just learned the basic ideas behind it. However, it seems to do essentially what I wanted. If anyone has a better (and comparably simple) version to post, I will happily accept that answer instead.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable basic approach. Don't forget, however, that `B.decode` discards the rest of `dat`. If you need to repeatedly read from `dat`, you need `B.decodeOrFail`, which returns the unread part of the bytestring.

Comment: Thanks for this info, @chi. Let me confirm that I understood that correctly: since my number (5) is small enough that the bytestring where it is encoded is mostly NUL, I could theoretically store more than one?

Comment: and in that case, I could use decodeOrFail to get the remaining data and have a second decode function grab another number from it?

Comment: I was not referring to the fact that most bytes are zero in your specific example. I was considering that, in the general case, you might want to perform multiple `BS.putStr` in sequence on the output side. In such case, on the input side, you need to read the first value, and then "consume" the input BS before reading the second value, and so on.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the help!